# Linking two projects in one solution visual studio 2013

Tags: c++

I'd like to compile one project depending of another one in the same solution. The problem is the following :
in my project one, in the main file I'm including camera.hpp and i call the constructor of camera. So i've got a error like LNK2001 because the compilator doesn't link the camera.cpp file who the constructor comes from.
Anybody can help me?
Sorry for my english.

Comment: Please provide the code, command you use to compile the project, and the exact error.

Comment: You mention two projects in one solution, but is this two programs (two .exe files created), in a two process project, or is the camera project a library project to be used by the main project?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to link the project having `camera.cpp` with the main project.

- Project 2: (containing camera.cpp ) Create a static/dynamic library.
- Project 1: (containing main ) Create the executable providing the *.lib* of the Project 2

Comment: Thank you, i'm just forgotten linking the lib of project (who contains camera.hpp). It's simple in fact.